# Nuxt vuex store not getting axios request

Tags: nuxt.js, vuex-modules

Have Nuxt axios module installed and works in index.js file but when I empty the index.js file and separate into its own module file (team.js) it doesn't work.

Team.js

```
export const state = () => ({
  teams: {},
})

export const mutations = {
  SET_TEAMS (state, value) {
    state.teams = value
  }
}

export const actions = {
async nuxtServerInit ({ commit }) {
  let {data} = await this.$axios.$get(`team`)
  commit('SET_TEAMS', data)
}
```

In the Vue dev tools it shows as - 
teams: Object
  teams: Object (empty)
what is the correct way to have Vuex modules? The documentation and other projects I've seen this should work

Comment: On usage of nuxtServerInit: "If you are using the Modules mode of the Vuex store, only the primary module (in store/index.js) will receive this action. You'll need to chain your module actions from there." [https://nuxtjs.org/guide/vuex-store#the-nuxtserverinit-action]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following up on my comment and sourced advice, your `store/teams.js` file can have it's own `nuxtServerInit`; but you can name it whatever you want because you'll need to explicitly dispatch it from your primary module (`store/index.js`).

---

`store/teams.js`

```
export const actions = {
  async nuxtServerInit({ commit }) {
    let {data} = await this.$axios.$get(`team`)
      commit('SET_TEAMS', data)
    }
  }
}
```

---

`store/index.js`

```
export const actions = {
  async nuxtServerInit({ dispatch }) {
    dispatch('teams/nuxtServerInit')
  }
}
```

Comment: You are right you do need to have the nuxtServerInit inside the store/index.js but the above won't work as you can't call it outside this file and nuxtServerInit is called once for each load so can't have duplicates. Don't know how I missed that, thanks